# What are some good progressions for beginning modeling?

Tags: modeling, polycount

New guy to Blender, want some advice on tutorial projects with small polycounts. So far I have modeled a pawn and a mug.

Comment: Please use the resources listed on [this page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender). Asking for links to tutorials is considered [off topic](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2380/what-is-the-proper-action-for-a-question-that-requests-links-to-tutorials). For broad questions or opinions, a forum format like [blenderartists](https://blenderartists.org/forum/s) might be more useful. To make better use of this site, ask focused questions on a specific topic. Please take the [Tour] and read the [help] section to understand how this site works.

Comment: Try a toy train or a low poly landscape. Or a toy train in a low poly landscape